# Real Analysis -Is ℚ ∩ [0,1) sequentially compact?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-explanation

So I've been given this question that asked whether ℚ ∩ [0,1)is sequentially compact, and I think it isn't due to the fact that it is neither bounded nor closed, but I am basing that off of instinct, so what is a formal way of justifying this?

Comment: You just need a counterexample: a sequence in $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1)$ that has no convergent subsequence (in the same set).  The easiest way to do that is to pick a sequence that converges in $\mathbb{R}$, but to a point not in $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

To show *directly* that your set does not satisfy the definition of "sequentially compact", you would give an example of a sequence that has subsequence that has a limit within the set.

For example, your sequence could be
$$ 0, \frac12, \frac23, \frac34, \frac45, \ldots, \frac{n-1}{n}, \ldots $$
Can you show that no subsequence of this has a limit in $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1)$?

(Hint: In $\mathbb R$, $1$ is a limit of every possible subsequence because ...? This implies ... because ...?)

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, what about when  Q∩[0,1]? this is just out of curiosity, because I think it is seq compact, but don't know for sure

Comment: @LiOu: For that you'll need a different counterexample, for example the one suggested by Chris Custer in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\Bbb Q$ is *dense* in $\Bbb R$, take a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)$ converging to, say, $\sqrt2-1$.  Then every subsequence converges to a point not in $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)$.

Comment: That won't do _as written_, because you have no guarantee that my "sequence in $\mathbb Q$ converging to $\sqrt2 - 1$" is a sequence of elements of $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1)$. I can perfectly well choose the first elements of my sequence as $41\frac23$ and $-5000$ (both of which are in $\mathbb Q$), and still have it converge to $\sqrt2-1$. But it wouldn't be a counterexample.

Comment: The sequence will eventually be in $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$.  Just take out a finite number of terms at the beginning,  if necessary.  That is, if you accept that there is a sequence in $\Bbb Q$ converging to any irrational,  that there is one in $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$ converging to $\sqrt2-1$ is clear.  @HenningMakholm

Comment: @HenningMakholm I've edited.